# How to account for non-prime numbers 0 and 1 in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers, zero, modulus

I'm not sure if this is the right place to be asking this, but I've been searching for a solution for this on my own for quite some time, so hopefully I've come to the right place.

When calculating prime numbers, the starting number that each number has to be divisible by is 2 to be a non-prime number. In my java program, I want to include all the non-prime numbers in the range from 0 to a certain number, so how do I include 0 and 1? Should I just have separate if and else-if statements for 0 and 1 that state that they are not prime numbers? I think that maybe 0 and 1 should be included in the java for loop, but I don't know how to go about doing that.

```
for (int i = 2; i < num; i++){
        if (num % i == 0){
            System.out.println(i + " is not a prime number. ");
        }
        else{
             System.out.println(i + " is a prime number. ");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is not correct. If num=91. Then this program prints 91 is prime 5 times (2 to 6) then it prints it is not prime.

```
boolean prime =true.
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++){// less than equal to sqrt num is good enough.
        if (num % i == 0){
            prime=false;
            break; // no more checks needed
   }    
}
if (prime && (num>1)){ // to cover case of num=0 and num=1
     System.out.println(i+" is Prime");
}
else{
     System.out.println(i+" is NOT Prime");
}
```

Yes I think you should include 1 and 0 as seperate cases. However note that 1 and 0 are neither prime nor composite. So take that into due consideration.

Comment: you can break a loop once you are sure it is false

Comment: yeah! nice suggestion! I will include this.

Comment: There is a better solution that runs in O(log n) time.
This is known as AKS algorithm. But for the current question I believe it is an overkill.
Here is the link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test

Comment: exactly, at beginner level this solution should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks! But how would I get the program to check whether or not 1 is prime and then based on that, have it output that it is not a prime number? Because I want it to display that 0 and 1 are not prime numbers with the program since 0 and 1 would be in the range from 0 to a given number x.

Comment: @shady The last condition takes care of that.

Comment: @shady: For num=0 or 1 the for loop doesnt run. So boolean prime remains true. However when printing, the condition is prime must be true and num>1, so it goes into else and prints 1 and 0 too. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Its perfect output for printing n Prime no's

```
double i,j;


    for ( i = 2; i <= num; i++){
        boolean prime =true;
        for(j= 2; j<= Math.sqrt(i); j++)
        {// less than equal to sqrt num is good enough.
            if (i % j == 0){

                prime=false;
                break; // no more checks needed
       }    

        }
            if (prime && (i>1)){ // to cover case of num=0 and num=1
                 System.out.println(i+" is Prime");

            }
            else{
                 System.out.println(i+" is NOT Prime");
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle them directly without trying to fit them in to your normal flow, since you know what they always will be.

If you really wanted them in your loop, you could do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    if (i > 1 && num % i == 0){
        System.out.println(i + " is not a prime number. ");
    }
    else{
         System.out.println(i + " is a prime number. ");
    }
}
```

Start at zero, and just add a check if you are above 1 so they are in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that
>   has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.

Also it is enough to check not until `num`, but `sqrt(num)`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (int)Math.sqrt(num); i++){// i=sqrt(num) has to be checked
```

Comment: for num=9, your answer is "prime". So if a number is perfect square, you need to include i=sqrt(num). Editing the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

To stick with your basic algorithm, I'd do it like this:

```
boolean maybePrime = num > 1;
int limit = (int) Math.sqrt(num);
for (int i = 2; maybePrime && i < limit; ++i) {
    maybePrime = num % i != 0;
}
if (maybePrime) {
    System.out.println(num+" is a prime number");
} else {
    System.out.println(num+" is not a prime number");
}
```

However, this is not very efficient. You might want to look into using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).